# Openquery reading date with 5 digit year, but python is failing

Tags: python, date, openquery

Trying to read some data from our postgres data using openquery and then also trying to read it using python using psycopg2 library.

in postgres there is a record with date column value: **194809-01-13**
when we query this record using openquery, it interprets this value as: **1948-03-23**

when connect to postgres DB using python, it throws an error: "year 194809 is out of range"

can someone help with this problem and also help me understand:

- how did openquery interpret 194809-01-13 to 1948-03-23
- and how to do the same via python

tried to read this column as String/Text, and python is able to read it, but it doesnt correct the date.

Need to understand logic used by openquery and do similar processing on python side

Comment: Which year should this be instead?

Comment: openquery is reading this correct, the year should be 1948 itself